URL not found when refreshing angular page and setting sourceMap to true
I'm runnign a multi-project app with angular
When refreshing the page I get an

The requested URL was not found on this server.

error.
I've tried a lot of .htaccess configurations and none of them worked when setting sourceMap to true in angular.json.
The server is apache and my current .htaccess file is
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

I get a AH00687 error code
here is my angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "synestez.io": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/synestez.io",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/sequencer/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/store/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "projects/sequencer/src/assets/styles/",
                "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/styles/",
                "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/styles/"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements":[ {
                "replace":"src/environments/environments.ts",
                "with":"src/environments/environment.production.ts"
              } ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements":[
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environments.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "staging"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build:production"
            },
            "staging": {
              "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build:staging"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "styles": [
            "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss",
            "src/styles.scss"
          ],
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets/styles/",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/styles/",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/styles/"
            ]
          },"assets": [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets",
            {
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/sequencer/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/store/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            }
          ]
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "store": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/store",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/store/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/store",
            "index": "projects/store/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/store/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/store/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/store/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/store/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/store/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "store:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "store:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "store:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/store/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/store/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/store/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/store/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sequencer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/sequencer",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/sequencer/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/sequencer",
            "index": "projects/sequencer/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/sequencer/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/sequencer/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "sequencer:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "sequencer:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "sequencer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/sequencer/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "dj-mixer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/dj-mixer",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/dj-mixer/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/dj-mixer",
            "index": "projects/dj-mixer/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/dj-mixer/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/dj-mixer/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",

          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build:development"

            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/dj-mixer/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "worklet-generator": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/worklet-generator",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/worklet-generator/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/worklet-generator",
            "index": "projects/worklet-generator/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/worklet-generator/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/worklet-generator/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/worklet-generator/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

here are my routes
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContactComponent } from '../../projects/store/src/app/contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../../projects/store/src/app/home/home.component';
import { WorkletGeneratorOrderComponent } from '../../projects/store/src/app/worklet-generator-order/worklet-generator-order.component';
import { WorkletGeneratorComponent } from '../../projects/store/src/app/worklet-generator/worklet-generator.component';
import { AppComponent as WorkletGeneratorAppComponent } from './../../projects/worklet-generator/src/app/app.component';
import { ContainerComponent } from './container/container.component';

export const routes: Routes = [{
  path:'',
  component:ContainerComponent,
  children:[{
    path:'',
    component:HomeComponent
  },{
    path:'worklet-generator/live',
    component:WorkletGeneratorAppComponent
  },{
    path:'worklet-generator/order',
    component:WorkletGeneratorOrderComponent
  },{
    path:'worklet-generator',
    component:WorkletGeneratorComponent
  },{
    path:'contact',
    component:ContactComponent
  }]
}];


Is your index.html also on the same root level as .htaccess config file? Also try to include this in your .htaccess 
AddType application/json .map


thank you but this doesn't work and yes I've included the htaccess inside the project folder

You could try including the following in your .htacess config so that source maps are served directly.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.map$ [NC]


I will try that If I get the problem again.Thanks
